# making folders with mv

Tags: linux

so I wanted to change a folders name from uppercase letters to lowercase letters, so I did

```
mv FOLDER folder
```

why am I not required to make a new folder?  Shouldn't I get an error like

```
folder does not exist
```

you can't copy into a folder that doesn't exist, so why can you move into one??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a difference between:

```
mv oldfolder/* newfolder
```

Where newfolder does not exist, and:

```
mv oldfolder newfolder
```

Where newfolder does not exist.

The first gives:

```
mv: target `newfolder' is not a directory
```

Whereas the second will rename oldfolder to newfolder.

Answer (score 10):

In UNIX/Linux, "mv" does one of two things:

1. Moves a file or directory from its current location (in one directory) to a new location (in a different directory).
2. Renames the file or directory, without moving it to a new location.

In the second case, renaming a directory doesn't create a new directory, it just changes the name of the already-existing directory.

In fact, your example does two different things, depending on whether "folder" exists as a directory already.  If it does, mv works as in the first case above, i.e. moves "FOLDER" into the "folder" directory, so it's now "folder/FOLDER".  On the other hand, if "folder" doesn't already exist, it just renames FOLDER.

Yes, it can be quite confusing!

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX *a folder is a special file*.

When you ask **`mv src dst`**, **`mv`** takes the file **`src`** and tries to move it to  **`dst`**. Several rules apply now. they are taken in order, the first one that matches is the one applied :

1. If **`dst`** doesn't exist, it will be the destination name (regardless of the type of `src`)
2. if **`dst`** already exists and is a directory, it will be considered as a *path* and not as the destination name. So the command will be understood as **`mv src dst/src`** and **`src`** is moved *inside* **`dst`** (the final path of a is **`dst/src`**)
3. if **`dst`** already exists and is not a directory, it will be erased only if **`src`** is not a directory.

Comment: Note that by "a folder is a special file", it doesn't mean the type of "special file" that is created by mknod.  It just means that folders (which are usually called directories in UNIX) are treated differently from files by "mv" and other commands.

Answer (score 0):

`mv` is also a renaming command. You are renaming one folder to a new name.